# How to do authentication using Akka HTTP

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

Looking for a good explanation on how to do authentication using akka HTTP. Given a route that looks like

```
val route = 
  path("account") {
    authenticateBasic(realm = "some realm", myAuthenticator) { user =>
      get {
        encodeResponseWith(Deflate) {
          complete {
            //do something here
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

[The documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0/scala/http/routing-dsl/index.html) outlines a way, but then the pertinent part performing the actual authentication is omitted...

```
// backend entry points
def myAuthenticator: Authenticator[User] = ???
```

Where can I find an example implementation of such an authenticator? I have the logic already for authenticating a user given a user name and password, but what i can't figure out is how to get a username/password (or token containing both) from the HTTP request (or RequestContext).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Authenticator is just a function `UserCredentials => Option[T]`, where [`UserCredentials`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0/index.html#akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.UserCredentials) in case of being (check with pattern matching) [`Provided`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0/index.html#akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.UserCredentials$$Provided) have `verifySecret(secret)` method which you need to safely call and return `Some` (Some user for example) in case of success, like:

```
def myAuthenticator: Authenticator[User] = {
  case p@Provided(username) =>
    if(p.verifySecret(myGetSecret(username))) Some(username) else None
  case Missing => None //you can throw an exeption here to get customized response otherwise it will be regular `CredentialsMissing` message

}
```

`myGetSecret` is your custom function which gets username and returns your secret (e.g. password), getting it possibly from database. `verifySecret` will securely compare (to avoid timing attack) provided password with your password from `myGetSecret`. Generally, "secret" is any hidden information (like hash of credentials or token) but in case of basic authentication it is just a plain password extracted from http headers.

If you need more customized approach - use `authenticateOrRejectWithChallenge` that gets `HttpCredentials` as an input, so you can extract provided password from there.

More info about authorization is [in scaladocs](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka-http/current/akka/http/scaladsl/server/directives/SecurityDirectives.html).

Comment: this is making more sense, but I don't understand the line
    `if(p.verifySecret(myGetSecret(username))`

Any chance you could explain a little bit about the secret calls?

Comment: @user1551604 `myGetSecret` is your custom function that gets `username` and returns your secret (e.g. password), getting it possibly from database. `verifySecret` will securely compare (to avoid timing attack) provided password with your password from myGetSecret

Comment: thank you for adding that. It does help a bit. So what is the parameter into the `myGetSecret` function? I guess it's just a string? What should it return? I have the password for users stored (in hashed form using BCrypt). Given  that, would it be the unhashed password?

Comment: @mattmar10 it takes String with username and returns string with plain password. If you have hashes - using basic authentication isn't recommended then as it doesn't actually support hashing a password. As it said in `P.S.` you can use `authenticateOrRejectWithChallenge` (see scaladocs and there is also sources - see link inside scaladoc). You can retrieve original provided password from there and calculate hash from it. Use [secure_==](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/release-2.3-dev/akka-http/src/main/scala/akka/http/scaladsl/server/directives/SecurityDirectives.scala#L212) to compare.